# Labeling the axes of my plot

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to add a label to the axes of my plot. This is my code:

```
    \begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[%
      % Lengend position
      legend pos = outer north east,
      % We need a tick for every data
      xtick = data,
      % The ticks label are provided in the file as the column named Num
      xticklabels from table = {test.dat}{Num}]
    % How the data are separated.
   % \pgfplotstableset{col sep = tab}
    % We need to simulate an x coord since it is litteral in the data file. I choose to index on the line.
    \addplot table [x expr = \lineno, y = Min] {test.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Min}
    \addplot table [x expr = \lineno, y = Moy] {test.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Moy}
    \addplot table [x expr = \lineno, y = Max] {test.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Max}
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Propagation d'une publication générée avec la politique est \bf {Amis Seulement}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The keys for adding labels to the axes are `xlabel` and `ylabel`. It's not too hard to find this in the [manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots).

Comment: The tag is pgfplots

Answer (score 2):

you might do either:

1. use `xlabel` and `ylabel` in the options part of the axis environment
2. use `\node at (axis cs:xmax,0) {your_x_label_here}` and `\node at (axis cs:0,ymax) {your_y_label_here}`

according to me, second way is easier when you need a more accurate label location by ajusting node options...

Comment: Your second approach only works if you set `clip=false` or use the `\node` command in the `after end axis/.code={...}`. A better way might be to use `xlabel` to set the label, and adjust the position using `xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin)}` or `xlabel style={at=(axis cs:<x>,<y>)}`