# pgfmathparse, foreach does not work inside axis

Tags: pgfplots

I and trying to use `foreach` loop and `pgfmathparse` inside `axis`. But it is giving me an error.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Default options for plots
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.12,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
    %tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    %label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={%
        %draw=none,
        font=\footnotesize,
        at={(0.5,1.0)}, % position of legend
        yshift=3pt,
        anchor=south,
        legend columns=2
        legend cell align=left,
        inner xsep=2pt,
        /tikz/column 2/.style={%
            column sep=4pt, % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80215/two-columns-in-legend-in-pgfplots
        },
        /tikz/column 1/.style={%
            column sep=2pt,
        },
        /tikz/column 3/.style={%
            column sep=2pt,
        },
        nodes={inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=0pt,text depth=0.15em},
        %nodes={inner xsep=2pt,inner ysep=0pt,text depth=0.15em}, % this added a space after the last text 
    },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=20cm,
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=1cm,
    ylabel={YLABEL},
    symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e,f},
    ticks=none,
    %xtick={a,b,c,d,e,f}, % adds legend at ticks
    %enlarge x limits=0.5,
    %enlarge x limits,
    enlarge y limits=0.2,
    nodes near coords,
    font=\footnotesize,
    grid=major,
    after end axis/.code={% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55261/labeling-the-axes-of-my-plot
        \node[below] at (xticklabel cs:0.25) {XXX};
        \node[below] at (xticklabel cs:0.75) {YYY};
    }
]

    \addplot coordinates {(a,5.42) (b,13.4) (c,10.69) (d,10.81) (e,30.31) (f,22.53)};
    \addplot coordinates {(a,0.72) (b,17.87) (c,5) (d,1.40) (e,12.39) (f,5.17)};
    \legend {Downlink,Uplink};

    \foreach \x/\y in {1/a,2/b,3/c,4/a,5/b,6/c)} {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\coor}{\x*(0.5/6)}
        \node[draw,anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs:\coor,0.8) {\y};
    };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is described in the manual of `pgfplots`, under section 8.1 *Utility commands*. I quote the relevant piece:

> Keep in mind that inside of an `axis` environment, all loop constructions (including custom loops,
>   `\foreach` and `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`) need to be handled with care: loop arguments can only
>   be used in places where they are immediately evaluated; but `pgfplots` postpones the evaluation of many macros. For example, to loop over something and to generate axis descriptions of the form `\node at (axis cs:\i,0.5)....`, the loop macro `\i` will be evaluated in `\end{axis}` – but at that time, the
>   loop is over and its value is lost. The correct way to handle such an application is to expand the loop
>   variable explicitly. For example:
>
> ```
> \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i/\j in {
> 1 / a,
> 2 / b,
> 3 / c
> }{
> \edef\temp{\noexpand\node at (axis cs: \i,0.5) {\j};}
> % \show\temp % lets TeX show you what \temp contains
> \temp
> }
> ```
>
> The example generates three loop iterations: `\i=1`, `\j=a`; then `\i=2`, `j=b`; then `\i=3`, `\j=c`. Inside of the
>   loop body, it expands them and assigns the result to a macro using an “expanded definition”, \edef.
>   The result no longer contains either `\i` or `\j` (since these have been expanded). Then, it invokes the
>   resulting macro. Details about the TEX command `\edef` and expansion control can be found in the
>   document TeX-programming-notes.pdf which comes with `pgfplots`.

So using the above construction the loop works:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Default options for plots
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.12,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
    %tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    %label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={%
        %draw=none,
        font=\footnotesize,
        at={(0.5,1.0)}, % position of legend
        yshift=3pt,
        anchor=south,
        legend columns=2
        legend cell align=left,
        inner xsep=2pt,
        /tikz/column 2/.style={%
            column sep=4pt, % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80215/two-columns-in-legend-in-pgfplots
        },
        /tikz/column 1/.style={%
            column sep=2pt,
        },
        /tikz/column 3/.style={%
            column sep=2pt,
        },
        nodes={inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=0pt,text depth=0.15em},
        %nodes={inner xsep=2pt,inner ysep=0pt,text depth=0.15em}, % this added a space after the last text 
    },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=20cm,
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=1cm,
    ylabel={YLABEL},
    symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e,f},
    ticks=none,
    %xtick={a,b,c,d,e,f}, % adds legend at ticks
    %enlarge x limits=0.5,
    %enlarge x limits,
    enlarge y limits=0.2,
    nodes near coords,
    font=\footnotesize,
    grid=major,
    after end axis/.code={% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55261/labeling-the-axes-of-my-plot
        \node[below] at (xticklabel cs:0.25) {XXX};
        \node[below] at (xticklabel cs:0.75) {YYY};
    }
]

    \addplot coordinates {(a,5.42) (b,13.4) (c,10.69) (d,10.81) (e,30.31) (f,22.53)};
    \addplot coordinates {(a,0.72) (b,17.87) (c,5) (d,1.40) (e,12.39) (f,5.17)};
    \legend {Downlink,Uplink};

    \foreach \x/\y in {1/a,2/b,3/c,4/a,5/b,6/c} {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\coor}{\x*(0.5/6)}
%        \node[draw,anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs:\coor,0.8) {\y};
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\node at (rel axis cs: \coor,0.8) {\y};}
        \temp
    };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```